Build the Affinity Matrix of Edge Preserving Multiscale Image Decomposition based on Local Extrema
In the paper Edge Preserving Multiscale Image Decomposition based on Local Extrema (Available at DSpace@MIT - Edge Preserving Multiscale Image Decomposition based on Local Extrema or the writer page Kartic Subr - Edge Preserving Multiscale Image Decomposition based on Local Extrema) a Laplacian Graph Matrix is composed in order to interpolate the image based on local extrema.
I wonder how efficient one build the matrix.
A C++ code I found (SHIH YA-FANG - Edge Preserving Blur) scales badly (Minutes).
I wonder also if the approach of interpolating the extrema found useful in other signal / image processing context.
Related to Interpolation by Solving a Minimization Problem (Optimization).

First, I managed to implement the algorithm:

For the image tested in the MATLAB code in the link (1463 × 2048) the code runs in ~30 seconds on Intel i7 8700K.
It can even farther optimized, but as a PoC it shows it is doable to do in seconds.
The main challenge is implementing the sparse interpolation in Colorization Using Optimization:
$$ \arg \min_{U} \sum_{\boldsymbol{r}} {\left( U \left( \boldsymbol{r} \right) - \sum_{\boldsymbol{s} \in \mathcal{N}_{\boldsymbol{r}}} {w}_{\boldsymbol{r}, \boldsymbol{s}} U \left( \boldsymbol{s} \right) \right)}^{2} $$

The image to be interpolated is given by $U$.
Location indices are given by $\boldsymbol{r}$ and $\boldsymbol{s}$.
The term ${w}_{\boldsymbol{r}, \boldsymbol{s}}$ is the relative weight (The edge on the graph) connecting $\boldsymbol{r}$ to $\boldsymbol{s}$.
The neighborhood relative to the index $\boldsymbol{r}$ is given by $\mathcal{N}_{\boldsymbol{r}}$. The connectivity is 4 or 8. The pixel itself is excluded (Acyclic graph).

The model means that a pixel is a weighted sum of the pixels around it.
The weighing is given by:
$$ {w}_{\boldsymbol{r}, \boldsymbol{s}} \propto \exp \left( - \frac{ { U \left( \boldsymbol{r} \right) - U \left( \boldsymbol{s} \right) }^{2} }{ 2 {\sigma}_{\boldsymbol{r}}^{2} } \right) $$
Where ${\sigma}_{\boldsymbol{r}}$ is the standard deviation in the neighborhood of $\boldsymbol{r}$.
Given the above, one could create an affinity matrix $\boldsymbol{W}$ given an image.
The matrix is not symmetric as weights are not symmetric due to the dependency on the local variance.
The matrix is normalized such that each row has a unit sum.
Remark: One could use uniform variance which will make the matrix a Symmetric Positive Definite matrix.
The paper add a constraint to the optimization problem by defining a set $\mathcal{V}$ of indices where the values of the pixels are forced. Hence the problem becomes:
$$ \arg \min_{U} \sum_{\boldsymbol{r}} {\left( U \left( \boldsymbol{r} \right) - \sum_{\boldsymbol{s} \in \mathcal{N}_{\boldsymbol{r}}} {w}_{\boldsymbol{r}, \boldsymbol{s}} U \left( \boldsymbol{s} \right) \right)}^{2} \quad \text{subject to} \quad U \left( \boldsymbol{p}_{i} \right) = {v}_{i} \; \forall \boldsymbol{p}_{i} \in \mathcal{V} $$
The code of the paper does not solve this exact problem:

It applies some adjustments to the weights by limiting the local variance.
Instead of forcing equality, for rows of pixels in the forced set it set the weight of the pixel to itself to $1$ and zero for all other weights.

It means it builds the problem intuitively. Not actual constraint but it pushiness by a square any shift form the forced value.
The matrix the code generates is "Pseudo Laplacian":

It has diagonal of 1.
On rows not related to the constraints the row has sum of zero.
On rows in the constraint it has a single value of on the diagonal.

The linear system has zero values for all pixels not constrained. So they need to obey the weighted sum of the neighborhood equals to the value of the interpolated pixel. The constrained pixels should be equal to the constrains. So the right hand vector has the forced values on those (Zero else).
Yet the system is solved in LS manner so the constraints are not exactly forced.
My code tries to follow the actual defined problem.
It forces equality by using the derivation in Interpolation by Solving a Minimization Problem (Optimization).
The trick to create the permute which defines the sub problem to solve.
It is well explained by the answer of @codehippo in Interpolation by Solving a Minimization Problem (Optimization).

The code is available on my StackOverflow GitHub Repository (Look at the SignalProcessing\Q95071 folder).
The code is implemented both in MATLAB and Julia.
